# Different values for scope variable based on condition using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a template with the following content:

```
<div class="container">
   <select class="first-selector">
      <option ng-repeat="item in ids">{{item.id}}</option>
   </select>
   <select class="second-selector">
      <option ng-repeat="item in values">{{item.value}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I will include this template dynamically to my app, a number of times.

**second-selector** will be populated based on the value selected in **first-selector**. `$scope.ids` will remain same, but based on the value selected in  **first-selector**, value in `$scope.values` should be changed, but it will affect all the other second-selector.

How can I resolve the issue, that the values in `$scope.values` should be different for each **second-selector**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive with the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive:

```
<div class="container">
   <select class="first-selector" ng-model="firstSel"
           ng-change="updateValues(firstSel)">
      <option ng-repeat="item in ids" ng-value="item.id">{{item.id}}</option>
   </select>
   <select class="second-selector" ng-model="secondSel">
      <option ng-repeat="item in values" ng-value="item.id">{{item.value}}
      </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.updateValues = function(sel) {
    //Update values here
};
```

For more information, see [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: i have multiple containers with pair of same select. then this solution will not work as expected

Answer (score -1):

Listen to `onchange` event on the first select and re-assign the value of `$scope.values` base on the selected `$scope.id`.

Comment: i have multiple containers with pair of same select. then this solution will not work as expected

Comment: What do you mean multiple containers? That's the only reasonable way to do it. It doesn't work because you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I work with angular 4 and i can tell you how i handle it and you can solve it using angualrjs: 
 you can listen to (ngModelChange) event like this:

```
<select class="form-control"
                          title="Choose one of the following..."
                          name="govSelect"
                          required
                          #gover="ngModel"
                          [(ngModel)]="selectedGov"
                          (ngModelChange)="onUpdateGov($event)">

                    <option *ngFor="let gov of allLookUps.governorateDataModels" value="{{gov.code}}">{{translate.currentLang === 'en-gb' ? gov.namePrimaryLang : gov.nameSecondaryLang}}</option>

                  </select>
```

and you can filter the second result in onUpdateGov() Method like this :

```
onUpdateGov(newGov) {
    this.selectedGov = newGov;

    this.allLookUps.governorateDataModels.filter(
      (governrate) => {
      if(governrate.code === newGov) {
        this.cities =  governrate.cityDataModels;
      }
    });
  }
```

and bind the second select on the result of the filter that will be on this case 
cities 
and this is the second select :

```
<select class="form-control"
                          title="Choose one of the following..."
                          name="citySelect"
                          [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
                          required
                          #cit="ngModel"
                          (ngModelChange)="onUpdateCity($event)">

                    <option *ngFor="let c of cities" value="{{c.code}}">{{translate.currentLang === 'en-gb' ? c.namePrimaryLang : c.nameSecondaryLang}}</option>

                  </select>
```

you can translate this to angularjs